# Leaflet: How read pixel dBZ values from the added rain-viewer layer

Tags: leaflet

I am requesting available weather past timestamps from Rain Viewer, below script tag clip:

```
...
init = function()
{
  var apiRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
  apiRequest.open("GET", "https://tilecache.rainviewer.com/api/maps.json", true);
  var o_that = this;
  apiRequest.onload = function(e) {
```

...

And then request Leaflet layers with "dBz" data

```
radarLayers[ts] = new L.TileLayer( 'https://tilecache.rainviewer.com/v2/radar/' + ts + '/256/{z}/{x}/{y}/0/0_0.png' , {
          tileSize: 256,
          opacity: 0.001,
          zIndex: ts
      });
```

I my application I want to check tile pixels for dBz values.
How I can do it JavaScript code?

Comment: [leaflet-tilelayer-colorpicker](https://github.com/frogcat/leaflet-tilelayer-colorpicker)

Comment: Thank you very much, it works perfectly.